# Where weblogic server gets that Java JDK address?

Tags: java, windows-10, keystore, weblogic12c

When I am installing weblogic 12.1.3, it proposes to choose some strange default java place: `c:\java\JDK18~1.0_6.`  I am setting the correct place of Java jdk: `c:\java\jdk1.8.0_66` instead.

But when I am looking at the Java Standard Trust Keystore, it is set in that default folder `C:\Java\JDK18~1.0_6\jre\lib\security\cacerts` Of course, at deployment the path cannot be resolved and a `CertPathValidatorException` is raised.

Where that weblogic gets that its default folder?

- It is not in environment. (JAVA_HOME is set to the correct folder)
- It is not in registry. ( I have searched in it)
- It is not in Oracle folder. (only in a AdminServer.log there)
- It is not on the whole computer ( I have searhed by total commander search for files containing JDK18)

in AdminServer.log:

```
java.home = C:\Java\JDK18~1.0_6\jre
```

If I run `domain\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd` in command line, AFTER that the folder indeed is present in several local env variables, including JAVA_HOME.

Where is it taken from and how? Where and how could I look for it? Have you ideas about further searching?

Edit.

1. Weblogic gets this folder from some unknown source twice - first during installation, second during first deployment of a domain.
2. The computer worked for some unknown projects before and it could have some java jdk folders with a similar name. Such name COULD be hidden somewhere. Now it is my only supposition about the source of the folder. But even if this is true, weblogic must get the name from somewhere. And all I want is to find that secret place in order to change its content.

Comment: looks like the DOS 8.3 file name to me. Windows somehow still has DOS compliant file names around. Are you sure, this location cannot be reached?

Comment: It could be related to the naming of your home directory. From https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24902_01/doc.91/e18840/install_config_12_1_3.htm#EOHWL219 : "Do not exceed a maximum of 12 characters when naming your home directory. If the name of this directory has more than 12 characters and if there are spaces in the directory name, the CLASSPATH may not be resolved properly."

Comment: @MiljenMikic but the correct name has only 11 letters and has no spaces... But thank you, your information surely will be useful someday.

Comment: @Henry The location cannot be reached, it does not exist. MAYBE, it existed before - the computer is not a new one and somebody worked on it. I thought about dos-changed name of some old and removed java jdk, too. The problem is that I can't find any signs of this name, but weblogic finds it and loves it.

Comment: The windows registry is another place where the name could hide.

Comment: @Henry I have noticed this in the question. I made a search in registry. No JDK18 line there

Comment: @Gangnus I believe they are referring to "Oracle Home directory", i.e. the directory where you are trying to install Weblogic..

Comment: @MiljenMikic This folder has nothing in common with the Oracle Home directory (C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home). We are speaking about Java jdk directory.

Comment: @Gangnus Of course, but how I understood their docs is that if we mess up with the name of Oracle Home directory, Weblogic will potentially fail to resolve classpath (can we consider JDK location as a part of classpath?) A long shot though, the error you are facing is quite bizarre.

Comment: @MiljenMikic I have all dirs at default, except the jdk dir and domain name... I don't want to find the error in the weblogic code - it won't help. I only want to find the source of that name in order to change it.

Comment: @Gangnus You have checked *all* environment variables (apart from JAVA_HOME) and no sign of `c:\java\JDK18~1.0_6.`?

Comment: @MiljenMikic Even no sign of JDK18... But thank you very much, it seems, I've found the source of the problem - it seams, one of weblogic scripts CREATES this name and puts it instead of JAVA_HOME! I will study the problem and put the answer here if I am right.

Comment: @Gangnus You can expect everything from Oracle :) +1 from me for the effort, good luck with resolving it.